# Is there a VBA method equivalent to the SQL SELECT query?

Tags: sql, excel, vba, select, autofilter

With an Excel Worksheet, I'm trying to search rows that matches some criteria in their cells value.

I need something like the SQL SELECT query to proceed search through Excel Worksheet, is there such method in VBA? A method that returns a Range of rows that matches the search criteria.

I have tried with the Range AutoFilter method but I can not use the returned object as a Range to access cells in the returned rows.

I'm really new to Excel VBA so sorry if my question looks strange or stupid

Comment: There is no direct equivalent in VBA.  You can run a SQL query directly against an Excel sheet, but that returns an ADO recordset and not a range of matching rows.  However if your rows have unique id's you could map back from the recordset to the rows.  If you use autofilter then the non-matching rows will be hidden, and you should be able to get the remaining rows fairly easily.

Comment: searching for something in a multi-column range, or as in a query looking in appropriate fields? Advanced filter allows you to do exactly this type of querying with criteria.

Comment: @Walidix: You could always use ADO to query the spreadsheet... As the above commenter stated it'll return an ADO recordset but you can easily find a way to manipulate that set however you need to.

Comment: ...You can use the `Range.CopyFromRecordset` method to write the ADO Recordset data to a worksheet or you can use the ADO `Recordset.GetRows` method with Excel's `Transpose` method to write data into a `Range` object.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the Union() function to create a range. Here's an simplified example (say you wanted to select the entire rows in which the value in the A column was an even number and highlight them yellow):

```
Sub UnionTest()

Dim myRange As Range
Dim cell As Range

For Each cell In Range("A1:A100")
    If cell Mod 2 = 0 Then
        If myRange Is Nothing Then
            Set myRange = cell
        Else
            Set myRange = Union(myRange, cell)
        End If
    End If
Next

myRange.EntireRow.Interior.Color = vbYellow

End Sub
```

Please note that you need to check if the range is empty or not before you use union on it (and color it but to make the code easier to read I have omitted it here), thus the If-Then statement. Depending on what you want to do to each row, it might be more effecient to just do the process on the row during the for-each loop.

Comment: "you need to check if the range is empty or not before you use union on i" - and before you colour it :)

Answer (score -1):

Hava a look at these funcitons

- [VLOOKUP](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/vlookup-HP005209335.aspx)
- HLOOKUP - same as VLookup but for rows
- LOOKUP()
- INDEX() and MATCH()
- OFFSET() and MATCH()

[How to find data in an Excel table](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/324861)
[How to Use VLOOKUP or HLOOKUP to find an exact match](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/181213)

Hope these help

Comment: These functions are not ideal to meet the question, ie return a range of rows.